# JUnit tests succeed individually, but when executed together fail and cause errors?

Tags: java, junit

I have three JUnit tests, which are shown below. These test all succeed if they are executed individually i.e. commenting out the two other tests and only executing one.

However, if I execute all three tests uncommented then "testOrderDatabaseReturnsOrdersCorrectly" produces an error and "testOrderDatabaseRemovesOrdersCorrectly" fails.

I really don't understand why this is happening. I'm using @Before to set up before each test, so the conditions for all three tests should be the same? Why are some of them failing when they work fine individually?

```
@Before
public void setup()
{
    sys = new OrderSystem();
    sys.getDb().clearDb();
}


@Test
public void testOrderDatabaseAddsOrders()
{
    sys.getDb().clearDb();
    sys.createOrder(25);
    assertEquals(sys.getDb().getDbArrayList().size(), 1);

    sys.createOrder(30);
    assertEquals(sys.getDb().getDbArrayList().size(), 2);

    sys.createOrder(35);
    assertEquals(sys.getDb().getDbArrayList().size(), 3);
}


@Test
public void testOrderDatabaseRemovesOrdersCorrectly()
{
    sys.createOrder(25);
    assertEquals(sys.getDb().getDbArrayList().size(), 1);
    sys.removeOrder("BRICK1");
    assertEquals(sys.getDb().getDbArrayList().size(), 0);
}

@Test
public void testOrderDatabaseReturnsOrdersCorrectly()
{
    System.out.println("Size of db: " + sys.getDb().getDbArrayList().size());
    sys.createOrder(25);
    System.out.println("Size of db: " + sys.getDb().getDbArrayList().size());
    BrickOrder o = sys.getOrder("BRICK1");
    assertEquals(o.getNumberOfBricks(), 25);
}
```

Comment: Is `sys` declared `static`?

Comment: Declared static where? @rgettman

Comment: If you mean in the test class, no it's just declared `private OrderSystem sys`

Comment: Post enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Compass NullPointerException, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I execute all three tests uncommented then "testOrderDatabaseReturnsOrdersCorrectly" produces an error and "testOrderDatabaseRemovesOrdersCorrectly" fails.

Your problem most likely is that the results from one of the test methods is not being cleared when the next test method is run and they are clashing.  Maybe you are using a memory database like H2 which is not being fully cleared even though you are calling `sys.getDb().clearDb();`?

Couple of ways you can verify this:

- First put a `System.out.println()` message in `setup()` to make sure it is being called before each method.
- At the start of your test methods, do a lookup in your database to see if there are results there to verify the `clearDb()` did something.  I suspect you will see that it isn't working fully.
- Change the test methods to use non overlapping tables or to use non overlapping data to see if that works.  For example, create a `int orderNumber` field and do a `++` on it in each test method to make sure you are using a new order.  This is a work around of course.  It would be better to understand why clear isn't doing what you want.

How to fix this is a more complicated problem that depends on what actually is backing your `db`.  Maybe you just have some bugs in your `clearDb()` method.  I mention H2 because even if you setup a brand new database connection, the old one never is destroyed and will be reused.  If it is a SQL database, fully dropping the tables and recreating them is one thing that forces even a persistent memory database like H2 to clear its stuff.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The db is simply an ArrayList, I called it a db for semantic sake. The clear method is literally just `AL.clear();`

Comment: The setup is being called before each test. I just don't understand how this can happen at all when the tests start with exactly the same conditions as if they were executed on their own.

Comment: What exactly is failing @Jakemangan1?  Does your arraylist have the wrong number of entries?  How many does it have?  Have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was causing the errors and strange test behaviour.

I had a field variable which was declared static. For some reason this was not being reset before each test, even though the sys variable was being reset each time. When I removed the static declaration for this variable all of the tests succeeded.

Comment: Aha.  So your order counter or something that auto-generated the name was static.  Makes sense.  It's certainly strange that the name of the order is auto-created when you are depending on it later to be `"BRICK1"`.  Maybe you should pass in the name to your `createOrder()`.